# How do I use vision API in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2, vision

I am a novice at ionic 2. Is there any way I could use google's vision API in my program? If so, could you explain it in simple terms due to the fact that I am generally quite new to the coding scene. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.. you should go through [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question would be closed as too broad.